# How can i match a substring in a big string with a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a IPv6 address with port also `[2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401]:1234`. I want to get the IPv6 address only in PHP. I am trying to do:

```
$str = "[2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401]:1234";
preg_match("[]", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

But this does not get me the proper result. 
I want `matches[1]` to contain only `"2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401:2401"`.

Comment: FYI: Paste your code in the question, don't use pastebin (unless the code is *way* too big to fit in the question, in which case, copy a snippet into the question).

Comment: Not sure why marked this question as duplicate as my question is to know the answer in PHP instead of a regular regex.

Comment: A regex is a regex.  The answers from that question should work here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preg_match` you're using won't work. You need something like this:

```
preg_match("/\[([0-9a-fA-F:]+)\]/", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: My IPv6 could contain alphabets also.

Comment: `[0-9a-fA-F:]+` hexadecimal

Comment: preg_match("/\[.*\]/", $str, $matches);
I ran this and got matches[0] = [1:2:3:4:5:6], but i want to exclude the square brackets also.

Comment: Try the code I posted now and check out what you'll get in `$matches[1]`

Comment: @AdiUlici: I want to exclude the [ ] square brackets out of the result. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I updated my answer now and put a tested version in which you'll have the wanted string in `$matches[1]`